# how to strongly type an action from a view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, actionlink, strong-typing

I'm very new to using the MVC system and I would like to know how to "strongly-type" the controller as opposed to using a string in an action-link residing in a view. I put strongly typed in quotes because I am still a bit unsure as to its usage. Would be correct in saying that I have strongly typed the model at the top of the next code=line?

Here's my view:

```
@model HtmlEditModel
<title> Input Yout Html </title>

@Html.BeginForm(
@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.HtmlInput))
<input type ="submit" /> 
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List page",
```

Here's my Action:

```
[HttpGet]
public virtual ActionResult HtmlEdit(
 ActionMode mode, 
 int? id = null, 
 string returnUrl = null) 
{
  return base.DataGet<HtmlEditModel, Html>(mode, ID, db.Htmls, returnUrl);
}
```

Comment: Can you please post a working version of the view, it seems to be lacking some code, perhaps a copy paste error?

Comment: The view is as much as I have. I don't know what to put as my second parameter because I don't want to use a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
@using(Html.BeginForm(action, controller)){ /*form fields go here*/}
```

I couldn't quite understand your comment, but after looking at your code I think you meant to say how to "remove" the ActionLink and bind the form to a specific action in a controller. Is this what you were asking for?